# Get number of configurable products with at least one in-stock associated product

Tags: product, configurable-product, performance, product-collection

I used following code to retrieve number of in-stock associated products in a category ($cat) for a huge store with thousands of products.

```
$cnt = 0;
$prods = $cat->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',  'configurable');

foreach( $prods as $product) {
             $simpleProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                                                  ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

            foreach( $simpleProducts as $simple ){
                   $cvc = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple);

                   if($cvc->getIsInStock() && $cvc->getQty() > 0) {
                          $cnt++;
                          break;
                   }
           }
}
```

Above code works but its really slow. I mean it takes almost half an hour to calculate number of products for all categories in my store. What's the problem ? I know I can use caching (and I already did) but the question is that how can I make the code faster or what I missed in the above code that made it really slow ?

**UPDATE**

I want to count all configurable products with at least one simple product in stock. I don't care about configurable product stock by it self, only its associated products matter because in my store configurable product's in-stock availability don't matter. Only its associated products is important. I.e: if a configurable have 3 in-stock products, we should count it once.

Comment: loading in a loop is a "no-no" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Tim said in him comment above ideally you don't want to be running load within a loop as this causes extra work and MySQL calls. (Making it "really slow")

I had a play around and I think I have a rough version of what your trying to achieve - get a count of configurable products who have at least 1 associated products that are in stock in category X?

May not be perfect, but should work and much faster too.

```
    <?php
//Update part 1 start
$eavAttribute = new Mage_Eav_Model_Mysql4_Entity_Attribute();
$code = $eavAttribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'status');
//Update part 1 end

    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

    //Gets all simple products that belong to a configurable product
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_product_collection')
        ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
        ->setFlag('product_children', true);

    //Adds stock, status and visibility filters.
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 1);

    //Filters by simple products who's parents are in the current category
    $productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('ccp' => 'catalog_category_product'),
        'link_table.parent_id=ccp.product_id',
        array('*'))->where('ccp.category_id = ?',$currentCat->getId())->group('parent_id');

//Update part 2 start
    $productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('statust' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'),
        'link_table.parent_id=statust.entity_id',
            array('value'))->where('statust.value = ?',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)->where('statust.attribute_id = ?',$code);

//Update part 2 end

    $cnt = $productCollection->count();
echo $cnt;

    ?>
```

Comment: @Good works.. James

Comment: Okay but this isn't what I want. I want to count all configurable products with at least one simple product in stock. I don't care about configurable product stock by it self, only its associated products matter because in my store configurable product's in-stock availability don't matter.

Comment: See update in the question.

Comment: OK Miko, no problem I missed the break; in your code.

 I have added the group->('parent_id') clause so now it will only count once per parent.

Comment: @JamesAnelay Great. There are also situations that associated simple products are enabled and in stock. But the parent product is disabled. Your code don't handle those.(tested) Trying to fix it. What do you suggest in between ?

Comment: See updates Miko, within //Update part 1 start and //Update part 2 start comments

Comment: @JamesAnelay So many thanks, great work. Its working but it needs more modifications to work only with the current store. i.e its enable for store 1 but not enabled for store 2. Also there is a default configuration if no config found.

Answer (score 1):

Just for Reference, I used sample data of magento 1.9, and this code broke. On debugging the reason was `count()` function. Magento 1.9 keeps surprising me, `getSize()` worked for me.

```
<?php

      $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

     //Gets all simple products that belong to a configurable product
     $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_product_collection')
        ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
        ->setFlag('product_children', true);

    //Adds stock, status and visibility filters.
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 1);

    //Filters by simple products who's parents are in the current category
    $productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('ccp' => 'catalog_category_product'),
        'link_table.parent_id=ccp.product_id',
        array('*'))->where('ccp.category_id = ?',$currentCat->getId());
    //getSize worked for me, in magento 1.9 with sample data installed.
    echo $productCollection->getSize();

    //$cnt = $productCollection->getCount(); error displayed
    echo $cnt;

    ?>
```